# Import sql dump using phppgadmin

Tags: phppgadmin

I have phppgadmin version 5.0.4, 
When I click button `SQL`  (in top-right of phppgadmin ) I must obtain window for importing sql dumps right? but in this window is only input text field for pasting sql file content

Question: where is button `choose file` for importing sql dumps in phppgadmin?

Comment: This should probably be moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 11):

The file input element is displayed while you are in some database detail after clicking the DB-specific menu item SQL only, not the upper right corner one.

You can find it easily on this image 
[image]

Comment: @RuyongaDan: After logging in, select the database you want to import the dump into. Then a detail of the DB is displayed and SQL menu item should be available (it should look like on the screenshot). Then just select the file and hit execute (also try unchecking 'Paginate results' box). I use phppgadmin 5.0.3