# Problem importing 'db.backup' to phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I know this will appear to be a duplicate of this 
[Import sql dump using phppgadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145877/import-sql-dump-using-phppgadmin)

However I AM clicking the correct place but I never get shown a Browse button.

I can't copy and paste either as file I've been provided is 'backup' format so I cannot open it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Right... in database.php
I commented out the maxsize check that blocks if maxsize is set to 0 - why would they do that?